# Piping timeout cmd to grep needs root

Tags: grep, timeout, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, piping

A bash noob here. Trying to write a one-line BLE tag presence detector for Home Assistant (build-in BLE module on RPI-3 slows Home Assistant significantly).

Need some help getting this work:

```
$ timeout -s SIGINT 5s hcitool -i hci0 lescan | grep 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

What's happening (or what should be happening):

1. hcitool is run for 5s (after 5s killed gracefully)
2. output is piped to grep for detection of one specific MAC
3. command returns the matched mac

However, this command doesn't return anything, only the statuscode 130 ($ echo $?)

This works however:

```
$ sudo timeout -s SIGINT 5s hcitool -i hci0 lescan | grep 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

And yes, I already setted the missing caps described in this thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96106/bluetooth-le-scan-as-non-root

Because of the setted capabilities, this also works as it should (returns a list of detected devices, killed gracefully after 5 seconds:

```
$ timeout -s SIGINT 5s hcitool -i hci0 lescan
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does it seems piping to grep needs root? (because I know it shouldn't)

Best regards,

Stephan

Answer (score 0):

Ah solved it ;)

Seems to the sequence of exection :). Using sudo has the same effect as using:

```
$ (timeout -s SIGINT 5s hcitool -i hci0 lescan | grep 00:00:00:00:00:00)
```